# Custom Angular 2 directive not working

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

**Error**
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'time-delta' since it isn't a known property of 'p'.

**Solution in documentation**
I have to add the Directive to declarations array. I've done this already.

Now my architecture:
I have three Modules:

- AppModule (root)
- TimeModule (should be a helper module later with some directives)
- AuthModule (Login, Sign up components and so on)

The AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        TimeModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AuthModule,
        routing,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

AuthModule:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        authRouting
    ],
    declarations: [
        AuthComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        SignupComponent,
        LogoutComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        AuthService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ LoginComponent ]
})
```

TimeModule:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ReadableDatePipe,
        TimeDeltaDirective
    ]
})
```

And now I am trying to use my TimeDeltaDirective in a view of LoginComponent.
And I already tried to add the directive to the other declarations arrays as well, but this won't work either.

I am thankful for any support! Thanks

TimeDeltaDirective:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[time-delta]' })
export class TimeDeltaDirective {
    constructor(renderer: Renderer, el: ElementRef) {
        function getTimeDelta(date: Date) {
            var now = new Date();
            return (now.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000;
        }

        this.delta = getTimeDelta(new Date(this.date));
    }

    @Input('date') date: string;
    delta: number;
}
```

usage in LoginComponent (example):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    template: `
    <p date="2016-09-28 00:00:00" [time-delta]>{{delta}}</p>
  `
})
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to export `TimeDeltaDirective` from your `TimeModule` and then import `TimeModule` in your `AuthModule` because your `LoginComponent` is decalred there, and that's where you want to use your directive. This way, `TimeDeltaDirective` will be available for use in `LoginComponent`, as well as in other declared components of `AuthModule`. So, it should be something like this:

**AuthModule**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        authRouting,
        TimeModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AuthComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        SignupComponent,
        LogoutComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        AuthService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ LoginComponent ]
})
```

**TimeModule**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ReadableDatePipe,
        TimeDeltaDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        TimeDeltaDirective
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this is not working. I added the `TimeDeltaDirective` to the exports array and added the same to the imports array of `AuthModule`. Still the same error. Any other idea?

Comment: @UeliKramer Did you add `TimeDeltaDirective` or `TimeModule` to `AuthModule` imports?

Comment: I've added `TimeModule` to imports.

Comment: @UeliKramer Then your imports/exports are all fine, maybe there's a problem with your directive, you should post it here.

Comment: Yes, I added to my post up above.

Comment: Do you have any advise for me?

Comment: @UeliKramer I can't find the error, it would be nice if you could reproduce this on plnkr. Here's quickstart, you can edit it to match your code: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: I know have another problem. in constructor() using console.log(this); console.log(this.date); returns in browser in TimeDeltaDirective object with the correct values and variables, if I output this.date it gives undefined. What is the reason for this? I am confused